# Ошибка при создании EDM в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp

Создал я значит БД, далее добавляю EDM в библиотеку классов. С базы данных данные о таблицах в виде диаграммы отображаются нормально, но при её сохранении выдаёт следующий эррор:

Ошибка      Выполнение преобразования: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0FA07AE171D73585A63B7707AD8774A18099B6D8E172A7B0020E7DBA31B122EDE8EA5BC9FACBE74786D1FA24D50E7A461BEBD384CE4D422F7E19BD3F7B89AA30.GeneratedTextTransformation.DynamicTextTransformation.get_GenerationEnvironment()
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0FA07AE171D73585A63B7707AD8774A18099B6D8E172A7B0020E7DBA31B122EDE8EA5BC9FACBE74786D1FA24D50E7A461BEBD384CE4D422F7E19BD3F7B89AA30.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTransformation)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0FA07AE171D73585A63B7707AD8774A18099B6D8E172A7B0020E7DBA31B122EDE8EA5BC9FACBE74786D1FA24D50E7A461BEBD384CE4D422F7E19BD3F7B89AA30.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTemplating)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0FA07AE171D73585A63B7707AD8774A18099B6D8E172A7B0020E7DBA31B122EDE8EA5BC9FACBE74786D1FA24D50E7A461BEBD384CE4D422F7E19BD3F7B89AA30.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(Object textTransformation)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0FA07AE171D73585A63B7707AD8774A18099B6D8E172A7B0020E7DBA31B122EDE8EA5BC9FACBE74786D1FA24D50E7A461BEBD384CE4D422F7E19BD3F7B89AA30.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()  DatabaseAccess
путь к проекту\файл бд.tt   1

Помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: Скрин IDE]